# class name is not declared in flex c++ scanner

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I am trying to generate a c++ scanner with flex, below is the message printed out by flex and g++.

```
|| flex -o step1_noinc.cpp --c++ --yyclass=step1_noinc  step1_noinc.lex
|| g++  -c step1_noinc.cpp
step1_noinc.cpp|345 col 21| error: ‘step1_noinc’ has not been declared                                                                                                                                              
||  #define YY_DECL int step1_noinc::yylex()
```

It says that the class name have not been declared, So what is going on?

I simplify my lex code as much as possible like below to ease debug :

```
%%

<*>\n {
}

%%
```

Comment: Can you provide the relevant portion of your code containing `step1_noinc`?

Comment: I edit the question with my simplified code

Comment: flex document says:"IMPORTANT: the present form of the scanning class is experimental and may change considerably between major releases." does this cause this problem? I use "flex 2.5.35" with ubuntu 1404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is up to you to define that class.

From the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Code_002dLevel-And-API-Options.html#index-yyclass):

> --yyclass=NAME, %option yyclass="NAME"
>
> only applies when generating a C++ scanner (the `--c++` option). It informs flex that **you** have derived `NAME` as a subclass of `yyFlexLexer`… (emphasis added)

Note the use of the word "you" in that sentence. Flex always defines the `yyFlexLexer` class (possibly changing the `yy` prefix), but it also allows you to subclass, in case you have several different similar scanners in a project.

Aside from changing the prefix `yy`, as far as I know you cannot modify the name of the class flex generates.

Comment: So I just need to remove the --yyclass=NAME?

Comment: Why did you use the --yyclass option? If you had some reason to do that, you'll need to find the correct way of doing whatever it was that you wanted to do. If you had no reason to use the option, then by all means get rid of it. Specifying options you don't need and/or don't understand is not really good engineering practice.

Comment: Aha, it works, so a further question is , in what case should I use --yclass?

Comment: See my answer, last phrase in the second last paragraph. In other words, use the option when you have some reason to subclass `yyFlexLexer`.

Comment: for example, I want to trace line number and file name of current lexer?@rici

Comment: sorry, I should be more specific, I subclass yyFlexlexer by adding fields to trace line number and filename of current buffer, and user this-> to refer to these field, but g++ says that the base class don't have such fields, how to resolve this ? @rici